# Unresolved variable in WebStorm, Angular 4

Tags: angular, authentication, webstorm

So I have an HTML-template, in which I refer to a service, defined in a constructor and WebStorm sends me this warnings about unresolved variables, although the variables to which I point are defined and linked to a service via import.

Here is the template:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a routerLink="/" class="navbar-brand">Recipe Book</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="/recipes">Recipies</a></li>
            <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="/shopping-list" >Shopping List</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <ng-template **[ngIf]="!authService.isAuthenticated()**">
        <li><a routerLink="/signup">Register</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/signin">LogIn</a></li>
      </ng-template>
            <li class="dropdown" app-dropdown>
                <a style="cursor: pointer" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" *ngIf="authService.isAuthenticated()">Manage <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a style="cursor: pointer" (click)="OnSave()">Save Data</a></li>
                    <li><a style="cursor: pointer" (click)="OnGet()">Fetch Data</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here is the TypeScript code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
import {RecipeDataService} from '../shared/RecipeData.service';
import {SignupUserService} from '../auth/signupUser.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent {
  constructor(private RecipeDataService: RecipeDataService,
              **private authService: SignupUserService**) { }
  OnSave()
  {
    this.RecipeDataService.OnSaveRecipe()
      .subscribe(
        (response: Response) =>
        {
          console.log(response);
        }
      );
  }
  OnGet()
  {
    this.RecipeDataService.OnGettingRecipe();
  }
}
```

and the contents of the service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';


@Injectable()

export class SignupUserService {
  token = '';
  signUpUser(email: string, password: string) {
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .catch(
        error => console.log(error)
      );
  }
  signInUser(email: string, password: string)
  {
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(
        response => {
          firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()
            .then(
              (token: string) => this.token = token
            );
        }
        )
      .catch (
        error => {console.log(error); }
      );
  }
  getToken() {
    firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()
      .then(
        (token: string) => this.token = token
      );
    return this.token;
  }
  isAuthenticated(): 
  {
    return this.token != null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you added your `SignupUserService` to the `providers` list in whatever module (AppModule, maybe) you are using this in? I know that the IDE I use will sometime complain when I am trying to use a service that has not been provided properly.

Comment: I did register my service in the Providers array, I’ve just double-checked this issue.

Comment: Does everything compile, and run? If so, sounds like something to ignore. Or, reload the IDE, and see if it persists. I have to do that with VS Code every so often.

Comment: It does compile and run, but the logic here is not applied. The Angular should display the elements of the list 'Sign In' and 'Log in' if I am not authenticated, so if isAuthenticated returns false, but it doesn’t display them, as it is supposed to. In the same time, I’m not authenticated, I can’t be, since I reloaded the app.

Comment: Perhaps, `return this.token != null;` should be `return this.token !== '';`. An empty string will not be null. The `this.token` is initialized as an empty string, not null. Is the : after `isAuthenticated()` just a typo?

Comment: Thank you, I should’ve defined as a string, not as a specific empty string. In this case your remark is valid and it made the whole snippet work!

Comment: : was a typo, but I wanted to explicitly show that it is a boolean in the end. I didn’t need to.

Comment: So, you are good now? Everything is working as you need?

Comment: I do! You helped a lot to find find an error.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I believe the reason was/is because the service was declared private in the constructor.
Change this:

```
constructor(private RecipeDataService: RecipeDataService,
              **private authService: SignupUserService**) { }
```

to this

```
constructor(private RecipeDataService: RecipeDataService,
              **public authService: SignupUserService**) { }
```

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23606?_ga=2.241092739.1642698293.1640193643-1459887653.1634674430